# PHP: hashing password and making text available

Tags: passwords

I think i get the whole password hashing and verifying login as I got it working with php.  however I need an answer and some advise and I dont mean dont eat yellow snow!!  :)

I want to store the passwords of users in a hashed format, however I have a need where by I need to be able to see or use given password so I can help the customer fix there issues as a technician.

Now passwords are first created by my system then issued to customer, however users have the choice to change their passwords if they so wish.

username is also created by system.

Now that being said:
I had 2 thoughts both of which I have no idea how to do so some pointer or an answer would be great.

idea 1:
is to have a button on my site to show only the technicians the user password on demand. so they can copy and paste to the site.

Idea 2:
I was also thinking that rather than see the password.  I could have some way to transfer the password into the site to create an auto login into the website.

So technician would have a button that they press and the password is sent to the site to auto login with the hashed password.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may use alternative method which does same thing without ever seeing the password. You may create "single-use" hashes and match them with users on request. When this hash is used (clicked), auto-login and remove hash. Also you may add expire-time for each hash. *Please never use Idea 1. NEVER.*

Answer (score 0):

To give technicians access to a user account, there is no need to know the users plaintext passwords. It is the job of your application to restrict access, so you can create an admin role which is able to impersonate a user.

Making passwords recoverable weakens the security of your site immensly.